# Python true/false and in

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to print out true if there is such letter/word and false if there isn't, but no matter what I type, it's always true.

```
phr1= raw_input("Enter a phrase or paragraph, and this will check if you have those letters/word in ur paragraph: ")
print "You entered: "+phr1
phr2= raw_input("Check if a word/letter exists in the paragraph: ")
phr2 in phr1
if True:
    print "true"
elif False:
    print "false"
input("Press enter")
```

When I run the code:

```
Enter a phrase or paragraph, and this will check if you have those letters/word in ur paragraph:
hello world
You entered: hello world
Check if a word/letter exists in the paragraph: g
true
Press enter
```

How is this possible, g dosen't exist, why does it say it does?

Comment: You never catch the value of `phr2 in phr1` and store it anywhere, so the following statements don't know anything about whether that check passed or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking `if True` will always pass, because the boolean expression being evaluated is simply `True`. Change your entire if/else to just be `print (phr2 in phr1)`

This will print "True" in the event that the second phrase is located in the first, and "False" otherwise. To get it to be lowercase (for whatever reason), you can use `.lower()` as detailed in the comment below.

In the event that you wanted to use your original if/else check (the advantage being that you can be more creative with your output message than just "True"/"False"), you would have to modify the code like this:

```
if phr2 in phr1:
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
input("Press enter")
```

Comment: To match his existing prints, he would probably want `print str(phr2 in phr1).lower()`

Comment: While that's true enough, I think that would make it a little bit less clean and harder to understand what's going on at a glance. I'll update to let him know the difference though.

Comment: +1 for actually having an explanation of what's going on instead of just code, but changing it to `if phr2 in phr1:` deserves a mention too.

Comment: Yes, the other answers to the problem are logically and syntactically valid alternatives...I just found them a bit wordy, and think this is a reasonable alternative. Checking `x in y` is itself a boolean comparison, and the problem's aim is to output a boolean value. Encouraging someone to write `if phr2 in phr1: print "true"` is almost as bad as writing `if True: print "true"`, and I won't do it.

Comment: @nbrooks - it's still valid in case the OP wanted to change the output to a more verbose string "It is in the string" or similar.

Comment: @jordanm Ah yes, I suppose that does make sense. Fair enough, I'll expound

Answer (score 1):

```
if <something>
```

means exactly what it says: it executes the code if `<something>` is true. The previous line of code is completely irrelevant.

```
phr2 in phr1
```

This means "check if `phr2` is in `phr1`, and then ignore the result completely" (because you do nothing with it).

```
if True:
```

This means "if `True` is true:", which it is.

If you want to test whether `phr2` is in `phr1`, then that's what you have to ask Python to do: `if phr2 in phr1:`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
phr1= raw_input("Enter a phrase or paragraph, and this will check if you have those letters/word in ur paragraph: ")
print "You entered: "+phr1
phr2= raw_input("Check if a word/letter exists in the paragraph: ")
if phr2 in phr1:
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
input("Press enter")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
phr1 = raw_input("Enter a phrase or paragraph, and this will check if you have those letters/word in ur paragraph: ")
print "You entered: "+phr1
phr2 = raw_input("Check if a word/letter exists in the paragraph: ")
if phr2 in phr1:
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
raw_input("Press enter")
```